# How to filter who completed goal based on event track

Tags: google-analytics, goal-tracking

I have a goal set in my site. And I would like to know how many users clicked in a button (which track an event) and then completed the goal. How can I do that in Google analytics?

I tried to use custom reports, to show how many users complete the goal, bu event label. And filtering by event label of interest. But it returns zero user completed the goal.

I think that the problem is that pageview (the goal is pageview based) and event are distinct concepts in Google analytics and somehow is difficult for Google to mix them.

My issue is related to report, not to implementing code.

Comment: I'll update with what I tried. But I'm not using the api, so there is no real code to share...

Comment: Maybe show the code you are using to track the event, and also your goal configuration.

Comment: I don't think I can't show the code due to policies of the company I work for. Does it affect the answer? I mean, do you think it may be a problem with the goal configuration? The event is being tracked, as well as the goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To users who completed your funnel - users that clicked the button and then completed the goal (a pageview) -, here goes my suggestion:
You can go to the **Behavior** report, in overview and click in **+ Add Segment**, and than in the red button **+ New Segment**. 
In this template, you can see in the bottom left a link called **Sequeces**. As new sequence you can set your event as the step one and your pageview as the second step. 
Than you set name and save your new Segment to use any time after.
Hope I've helped.